# Launching fmxl GUI using javafx on Eclipse, Error in start method

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to launch a fmxl file using eclipse.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class MainProgram extends Application {

public void start(Stage stage) {

    try {

        FXMLLoader fmxlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        String viewerFxml = "Interface.fmxl";
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)fmxlLoader.load(
                this.getClass().getResource(viewerFxml).openStream());
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.exit(1);

    }
   }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

However, I keep getting this error.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at MainProgram.start(MainProgram.java:20)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application MainProgram
```

The code appears to run up until this line:
AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane)fmxlLoader.load(
                    this.getClass().getResource(viewerFxml).openStream());

Really not sure why I'm getting this error.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You would get that error if the path to the FXML resource is incorrect

Comment: (E.g. you have `Interface.fmxl`, which should probably at least be `Interface.fxml`, though there may be other issues. )

Answer (score 0):

It is because the path of file which has to be loaded is not correct.
Try putting the correct file path in your String variable.
that is
String viewerFxml= "*~path*/Interface.fxml";

Comment: No, this doesn't work I'm afraid. The Interface.fxml file is within the same package as the the MainProgram.class file in eclipse.

I tried it with the complete path but I continue to get the same error.

Comment: Got it. .fmxl instead of .fxml was causing the issue.
Thank you very much